# Secure meteor admin functionality

Tags: meteor

I have a couple of admin functions I want to add to a meteor site and was wandering what is the best way to create, hide and protect them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods). Just be sure to only include them on the server, by placing the code in a folder called `server/` E.g.

`server/admin.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function (arg1, arg2) {
    // confirm that the user is an admin
    if ( ! this.user.isAdmin )
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You are not authorized to perform this action");
    // perform task
    return "some return value";
  }
});
```