# Meteor: SSR necessary to secure admin part of application?

Tags: security, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-methods

I have my extended user model in the `Meteor.users` collection, which I'm publishing most fields from to the client. Each user has an `isAdmin` field, set to `false` by default.

Now I have two concerns, which are linked:

1. > How to make sure, components meant for admins can only be rendered, if the `isAdmin` field in the `Meteor.users` collection is set to `true`?
2. > How to make sure, the `isAdmin` field on the `Meteor.users` collection cannot be modified from the clients console?

---

### Concerning *1.*

I'm hesitant to publish this field to the client and simply evaluate `isAdmin` on the client side.

I'm not sure if there is some hackish way through the console to simply change `isAdmin` in a way that would allow to render the component (or part of it) that is only meant for admins on the *client*. I could imagine that it is possible with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to do so, for example.

> Should I use `server-side rendering` to secure the admin part of my UI?

---

### Concerning *2.*

Consider the first paragraph on *Profile editing* in this [article](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) about common mistakes. It suggests that `isAdmin` could easily be changed from the client by calling `Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {'isAdmin': true}})` from the console.

When I run it, being logged in to my application, I get `update failed: Access denied` though.

But even the official documentation still suggests to add

```
// Deny all client-side updates on the Lists collection
Lists.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; },
});
```

at https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667307/8412038), suggesting that it's enough to simply check for the `isAdmin` property on the server side, if you make sure that the `Meteor.methods` are server-only. But it doesn't talk about `allow-deny` at all and it's 6 years old.

> Can anyone tell, what truly is the case as of today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell, what truly is the case as of today?

I would not put too much effort to secure the admin ui on the client. A router level redirect when `isAdmin` is false should be sufficient.*

Way more important here is to secure methods and publications because these are the parts where users can mess around with your application. For those it can't be secure enough:

- use `ValidatedMethod` from [`mdg:validated-methods`](https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/validated-method) for Methods
- write a factory function to create Publications similar to `mdg:validated-method` to allow basic checks in a mixin-style
- both: check if the arguments are valid
- both: check if the user exists
- both: check if the user has sufficient roles -> I recomment [`alanning:roles`](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) as it makes permission level checks more secure as it checks for id-match existence in a dedicated collection rather than checking for a flag in the user collection (plus it decouples the users from the roles!)
- Throw fast and a lot: throw on any suspicious inconsistency, try to cover any undefined state with throwing errors.
- rate limit using [`ddp-rate-limiter`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp-rate-limiter) every method and publication
- write a simple sanity check on startup that ensures all methods and publications are rate-limited, you can get all registered methods/publications on the server at `Meteor.startup` via `Meteor.server.method_handlers` and `Meteor.server.publish_handlers`
- write test a lot, especially for the admin related methods and try any weird and crazy input you can think of to see if it gets rejected or causes any weird behavior (which you want to avoid)

As far as I understood your question you have currently not integrated ssr and if you follow the above steps you can secure your admin-area of the application a lot without including ssr into your app (which itself can cause a lot of headache due to additional config etc.).

*if you decide to use the recommended `alanning:roles` package you would be better to also use it on the client to check the user's roles.

Comment: I would highlight that UI itself (i.e. templates) is almost impossible to secure, even with dynamic import. But data and actions (i.e. publications and methods, as you  describe) are normally what is at stake.